# jQuery select(live, change) and .ajax only firing once

Tags: jquery, codeigniter-2

I have a page that has 52 drop-down menus with the class of regionalSelect.

I have bound the change event to trigger an ajax run to the controller to save to the database and the success callback function is to refresh the page.

After the refresh, the functionality no longer works.

I place this code is my document ready

```
 $("select.regionalSelect").live('change', function(){
        var sel = $(this).val();
        var id =      $(this).parent().parent().find("td[name=propNumber]").html();

        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo site_url('conn/reassignRegional'); ?>",
            type: 'POST',
            data:{ id: id, regional: sel },
            success: function(msg){
                var link = "<?php echo site_url('conn/PropertiesAndRegions'); ?>";
                window.location.href=link;  
            } // end success
        }); // end ajax

    }); // end change
```

The controller just takes the posted values and inserts it into the database. When the page refreshes, the list is correct but additional changes can't be made.

Since I am presenting a list of our properties and their current regional directors and a mechanism to change as regionals get reassigned, the continued availability of editing is a necessity.

I have been staring at this a while and I am not that experienced a coder as it is, so I decided to ask for fresh eyes.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: Do you need to be using `.live()`? You might be able to use `$('select.regionalSelect').change(function() {` instead, which has mostly the same behavior but a different purpose. Also, when redirecting with JS, you should assign your link to `window.location.href` instead of just `window.location`. And make sure your AJAX requests are cached (POSTs shouldn't be, but you never know).

Comment: Do you have javascript errors?

Comment: I am using .live because the grid isn't there at load but are ajaxed in

Comment: You might try using `location.reload(true)` which forces a server refresh.  That being said, if you are going to refresh the page, why use AJAX at all?  Just use good old fashioned `form.submit()`.  Or, do use AJAX but skip the page refresh.  Use JavaScript to update the page if necessary.

Comment: perhaps this is where my inexperience is showing. I am not using forms  but just using the change of the select to trigger an ajax transfer of data. The thought of 52 forms on a page and 52 submit buttons did not appeal to me.

Comment: @Cory Larson, I rewrote the view so that the grid was present at load and changes from .live to .change as you suggested. I also added the href to the refresh. The page is now working fine. Is there a way to "accept" a comment as the correct response???

Comment: You can't accept a comment, however you can answer your question yourself putting this info in (and thanking Cory) and accept it that way :)

Comment: I think SO needs a way to promote a comment to an answer -- I'll help you out by duplicating my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need to be using `.live()`? If your select elements aren't being added dynamically to the page after it loads, then it isn't necessary. Instead, you might be able to use

```
$('select.regionalSelect').change(function() {
    ...
});
```

instead, which has mostly the same behavior but a different purpose.

Also, when redirecting with JS, you should assign your link to `window.location.href` instead of just `window.location`. And make sure your AJAX requests aren't cached (POSTs shouldn't be, but you never know).

To disable cache globally for jQuery, you can do this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});
```